# Disable Intel HD graphics (Baytrail) overscan so a tablet that uses it can better sync with TV?

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, resolution, intel-graphics, overscan

I have a Windows 8.1 tablet with an Intel Atom Z3735F SoC. This has an integrated Intel HD GPU.

The tablet has an micro HDMI port at which I want to attach a TV.

But on the TV I only get a signal with an huge overscan (black frame around the screen).

I checked the reason for that: My tablet runs at a resolution of 1280x800 which is the same resolution I selected for the tv (HDMI port). But the TV says it gets a 1920x1080 resolution. And in this HD image is the tablet screen centered.

I tried multiple configurations and settings, but the only way in which I get a fullscreen image on the TV is when i set 1920x1080 as a resolution. Which is bad because I can't use the tablet screen in full HD.

I already un/installed the newest driver multiple times.

I also tried [this solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20151214232349/http://www.intel.com:80/support/graphics/sb/CS-029478.htm) but the customModeApp will not work with the newest drivers anymore.

I have searched the Intel forum for hours, where  multiple people reported the same issue. Unfortunately without an real solution.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the TV have a setting for the resolution? And a setting to make the image fill the display area?

Comment: The TV just displays the image comming in. I tried it by using the hdmi signal of my android phone. This is displayed full screen even if it is not 1080p.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that most resolutions will display a centered image with black borders on all sides. I connected my Z3735F Chuwi Vi8 tablet to a Samsung and an LG television. Only on some resolutions you can select "Maintain display scaling", which will remove the black borders on your TV.

Resolutions that work for me are:

- 1920 × 1080
- 1360 × 768 (LG only)
- 1280 × 720

The 1280 × 720 resolution allows me to mirror the display of my tablet (1280 × 800) to the TV, losing only 80 pixels.

To set the "Maintain display scaling" option do this:

- If you have a keyboard connected,
  press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

Alternatively,

- Right click on the desktop
- Select "Graphics options" → "Panel fit" → Your 2nd display → "Maintain display scaling"

If the "Maintain display scaling" option is not there, you will have to select a different resolution and try again.